# error with installing virtualenv with python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, python-2.7, virtualenv

ive updated to python3 and downloaded virtualenv using:
 `sudo /usr/bin/easy_install virtualenv`

when i go to start the virtualenv i got the following error message :
`virtualenv project1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/virtualenv", line 6, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3241, in <module>
    @_call_aside
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3225, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3254, in _initialize_master_working_set
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 585, in _build_master
    return cls._build_from_requirements(__requires__)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 598, in _build_from_requirements
    dists = ws.resolve(reqs, Environment())
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 786, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'zipp>=0.4' distribution was not found and is required by importlib-resources`

i looked around and realised the that 'zipp' had not been installed so i installed that also. when i went to run the virtualenv again i got the same error message again as above. and for some reason it keeps referencing python 2.7 even though ive upgraded to python3.

Comment: What if you use `virtualenv -p /path/to/python3 project1` (where you replace the `/path/to/python3` with the path to the python3 executable).

Comment: sorry im new to all this. what do you mean by "path to the python3 executable"?

Comment: maybe follow the installation instructions from the docs https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/installation.html

Comment: @hbk1414: well somewhere in the system there is a program `python3` this is the "interpreter". You perhaps can find it with `whereis python3`.

Comment: virtualenvwrapper is also a nice tool to use with virtualenv - https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem even after including the path to python3. it still came up with the same error

Answer (score 2):

please try this ..

you just follow Exactly the bellow Items :

Open your Command Prompt AS ADMINISTRATOR -> right click on CMD and RUN AS ADMINISTRATOR

go to which Folder to you want to create your VirtualENV : For example : > Cd C:\Users...\Documents\python\src

type it : `PIP install Virtualenv`
make sure your internet connection is Ok

4.type : `python -m venv env`

and then you can create your project inside this env folder..

all Comment code should be write in Command Prompt AS Administrator

Comment: I dont think he's on a windows machine

Comment: Dude you just save my life

Answer (score 0):

i ended up using the built in python 3 venv package. it works just as well and it was straight forward and simple. thank you for all the help

start the virtual environment: `python3 -m venv project1`
activate the virtual environment: `source project1/bin/activate`
deactivate the virtual environment: `deactivate`

Answer (score -1):

If you're using Python 3.3 or later, you can use the built-in venv [https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html] module.  This will reduce the number of dependencies, making installation and troubleshooting a bit easier.

To double-check that you are invoking the correct Python interpreter, run `python3 -V` or `python -V` (depending on how it's aliased).

Answer (score -1):

Just try out.

virtualenv venv

It should create a venv directory in same directory if python 3.x is being used.